# $f(x)$ from $f(g(x))$

Tags: functions, special-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Is it always possible to find $f(x)$ if the composite function $h(x) = f(g(x))$ and $g(x)$ are given?

In other words, can there be any cases where, for given $h(x)$, we can not express it in an explicit function of $g(x)$?

Comment: I believe we can find candidates but not the exact function

Comment: h(x)=x, g(x)=x^2.. you can't find the negative numbers there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $g(x)$ is invertible then
$$f(x) = h(g^{-1}(x)).$$
What happens if $g(x)$ is not invertible. Consider, e.g., $f(x)=x$ and $g(x) = 1$.